# Create a directory list printer

Tags: linux, bash, shell

On Windows there are many programs that can recursively print a detailed list of directory contents. I haven't found any for Linux and so I'm trying to create a script that does so.

This is what I'm going for:

- For each file print full path name(Tab)size in Mb(Tab)file extension
- If there are several directories, skip a line for each different directory traversed.
- For the directory name, print the directory name and leave blank-spaced tabs for extension and size.

Sample output is as follows:

```
Path and Name   Size MiB    Extension   

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\beers\         
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\beer1\- random name.pdf    5.11    pdf 
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\beer1\- random name2.djvu  5.11    djvu    

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\beer2\         
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\beer2\- random name.mp4    253.91  mp4
```

Based on a user comment and some research, I have:

```
ls -R -lh /mnt/folder300/ | cut -d' ' -f 5- > folder300.txt
```

With this, I intend to take the output of `ls -R -lh` and omit the first 4 fields.
But, I notice this clips text for example on nested directories. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ls -R -l` does something similar. I don't think you need to write a script for that.

Comment: @oguzismail: I tried what you suggested, but there's a small problem. Please see the revised question for further details.

Answer (score 1):

This bash command give size and full path

> find ~+ -type f -maxdepth 100 -exec du -bh {} ;